# Qt Creator menu bar is missing on Lubuntu 15.10

Tags: lubuntu, qt-creator

I've just installed Qt 5.5.1 on Lunbuntu 15.10. The main menu bar of Qt Creator is invisible, but I can click it. How do I fix this?

[image: image description]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of qtcreator package in all ubuntu flavors of 15.10 is built agianst qt 5.4  and you just installed qt 5.5 and I am not sure of the breakage. you might be able to see for yourself if you go to the help menu and select about Qt. I am pretty sure different version of Qt with the second version number is not really supported well so this may cause your problem as it is trying to display qt 5.5 when the qtcreator you have installed is qt 5.4. If you want to use qtcreator with qt5.5 you may have to  build it from source against qt 5.5 or find someone that has built it with qt5.5. Qt is a widget toolkit and as such it draws the program on the screen and you have tried to basically take qt 5.4 out of the hood and put qt 5.5 and expected it to just work.

If using qtcreator is more important to you than say new stuff in qt 5.5 you could reinstall the Qt 5.4 that is in the repos. However to properly do that more info on how you installed Qt 5.5 would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the 'Platform Theme' to nothing:

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=
```

or removing the `appmenu-qt5` package:

```
sudo remove appmenu-qt5
```

so the Qt5 extended/customized menu rendering is not used.  Then restart Qt Creator as normal.

```
qtcreator
```

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appmenu-qt5/+bug/1307619

Answer (score 0):

It's a desktop setting in Ubuntu. Go into `settings/appearance/behavior` and check the options for show the menu in the window's title bar and for always show menus. This fixed it for me - all my apps - QtCreator included - now behave correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Recently had similar problem on KDE Plasma. Turned out I had widget "Global Menu" in one of my panels. Removing it, fixed the qt creator's menu problem.